# Pass json data to input field

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

Can anyone help me why I can't pass the json data on the text field? I got this error when I open my modal: Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined. Thanks so much! :)

```
    public function generateEmployeeId() {
        $number = getTotalEmployees();
        $employee_id = 'ACZ'. date("Y") . $number;
        echo json_encode (['employee_id' => $employee_id]);
    }
     
    public function getTotalEmployees() {
        $num = 1;
        ++$num;
       
        $len = strlen($num);
        for($i = $len; $i < 3; ++$i) {
            $num = '0' . $num;
        }
       
        return $num;
     }
```

Function to open modal and retrieve employee id

```
function modal_add_employee() {
    $('#modal_employee').modal('show');
    $('#data-submit--employee').html('Add Employee');
    $('#modal_employee').find($('#staff_id')).val('');
    $('#modal_employee').find($('#employee_lastname')).val('');
    $('#modal_employee').find($('#employee_firstname')).val('');
    $('#modal_employee').find($('#employee_middlename')).val('');
    $('#modal_employee').find($('#employee_email')).val('');
    $('#modal_employee').find($('#employee_id')).val(data.employee_id);
    $('#modal_employee').find($('#employee_contact')).val('');
    $('#modal_employee').find($('#employee_address')).val('');
    $('#modal_employee').find($('#employee_birthdate')).val('');
    $('#modal_employee').find($('#employee_gender')).val("Male");
}
```

Comment: On modal_add_employee js function, you used data.employee_id, where is this data variable defined?

Comment: I think the data variable defined is not defined yet. Where can I define it? I'm new to ajax and json.

Comment: How modal_add_employee function executed? When you click on a button, right? And do you use any framework for PHP?

Comment: Yes, when I click the button it will show the modal. I don't use any framework for PHP.

Comment: Can you update all your PHP codes in that file?

Comment: What should I do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224455/discussion-between-james-dinh-and-j-wujeck).

Answer (score 0):

Look like you are studying OOP. To call an AJAX for this, you can follow these steps:

1. Create a new PHP file corresponding to getting data from AJAX. Let's call it action.php:

```
<?php

include 'your_oop_file.php';

$object = new <Your defined OOP class>;
// Your logical process AJAX request
echo $object->generateEmployeeId();

?>
```

2. Change JS function into

```
function modal_add_employee() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'action.php',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#modal_employee').modal('show');
            $('#data-submit--employee').html('Add Employee');
            $('#modal_employee').find($('#staff_id')).val('');
            $('#modal_employee').find($('#employee_lastname')).val('');
            $('#modal_employee').find($('#employee_firstname')).val('');
            $('#modal_employee').find($('#employee_middlename')).val('');
            $('#modal_employee').find($('#employee_email')).val('');
            $('#modal_employee').find($('#employee_id')).val(data.employee_id);
            $('#modal_employee').find($('#employee_contact')).val('');
            $('#modal_employee').find($('#employee_address')).val('');
            $('#modal_employee').find($('#employee_birthdate')).val('');
            $('#modal_employee').find($('#employee_gender')).val("Male");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you answer my chat? Thanks.